# How to show online directory in android

Tags: android, list, directory

I have a download host that has many directory, 
How can i show these online directories in an android application?

I prefer not to use WebView because does not have diffrent to browser!

and this is my host : http://51.254.93.66/Shikfa/

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is a WebView in android:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

  WebView mWebView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://51.254.93.66/Shikfa/");

  }
}
```

And then your main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

It should show all your directories like it does on your website.

Comment: no i knew webview but webview is like to use browser! i want to you know list these directories in list view or something , at least is there any other way than using webview?